# Attempting to install the Release version on my device gets conflict profiles

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to install the Release version of my app on my device to test it.

When I select the *Edit* > *Scheme* and under RUN I choose "*Release*" for **Build Configuration**

[image]

But I get the error:

> My App has conflicting provisioning settings. My App is automatically
>   signed for development, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone
>   Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code signing
>   identity value to "iPhone Developer" in the build settings editor, or
>   switch to manual signing in the project editor. Code signing is
>   required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

I have gone to Code Signing and Ensured that my release is my **iOS Distribution**

I have deleted all my profile, certs and re-imported. I have cleaned the build. I have removed my account.

When I switch to Manual Signing I get the error:

```
No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found
No "iOS Distribution" signing certificate matching team ID "XXXXXXXXXX" with a private key was found.
```

But it is in my KeyChain.

I'm so frustrated. Has anyone else solved this?

Comment: You can't install a release build

Comment: Then how do I test if push notifications from the release build? Not the sandbox?

Comment: You can use TestFlight.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to use the iOS developer profile when running builds on your device. You can build in release mode still. However you can't install distribution signed binaries through Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ad-hoc profile to test push notification for the release build. It is same as the distribution build.